# Adding signature in pdf (jpeg or png) format with a bottom border

Tags: formatting, rules

I currently have this layout:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\textbf{Position} \par \medskip
\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=1.5cm]{Example_Signature.png}\\
\makebox[2.0in]{\hrulefill}\\

\qquad\qquad\quad \textbf{Signature}
\columnbreak \\
\textbf{Position} \par \medskip
\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=1.5cm]{Example_Signature.png} \\
\makebox[2.0in]{\hrulefill}\\

\qquad\qquad\quad \textbf{Signature}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

What looks like this:

[image: Signature field example]

I want to make it look better, aligning all the fields and have smaller spaces in-between. Something similar to this:

[image: Better example of signature field]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a 3 column - table?

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\raggedright}X}

\begin{document}


\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{3}{@{}Z@{}}}
  \textbf{Position} & & \textbf{Position} \tabularnewline
  \includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth,height=1.5cm]{Example_Signature.png} & & \includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth,height=1.5cm]{Example_Signature.png} \tabularnewline
  \cline{1-1} \cline{3-3}
  & & \tabularnewline
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{\bfseries Signature} & & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\bfseries Signature} \tabularnewline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update** Some better spacings:

Change the relevant lengths and the scaling of the signature images to the real needs. The space between is controlled with `\spacebetween`.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newlength{\spacebetween}
\setlength{\spacebetween}{2cm}

\newlength{\signaturerulewidth}
\setlength{\signaturerulewidth}{1.5pt}
\newlength{\fullwidth}
\setlength{\fullwidth}{0.7\linewidth}


\begin{document}

{%
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\fullwidth}{@{}X@{}p{\spacebetween}@{}X@{}}
  \textbf{Position} & & \textbf{Position} \tabularnewline
  \includegraphics[width=0.33\fullwidth,height=1.5cm]{ludwig-van-beethoven_330.jpg} & & \includegraphics[width=0.33\fullwidth,height=1.5cm]{pablo-picasso_330.jpg} \tabularnewline
  \cmidrule[\signaturerulewidth]{1-1} \cmidrule[\signaturerulewidth]{3-3}%[1pt]
  %& & \tabularnewline
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries Signature} & & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries Signature} \tabularnewline
\end{tabularx}

}

\vskip2\baselineskip
{%
\setlength{\spacebetween}{1cm}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\fullwidth}{@{}X@{}p{\spacebetween}@{}X@{}}
  \textbf{Position} & & \textbf{Position} \tabularnewline
  \includegraphics[width=0.33\fullwidth,height=1.5cm]{ludwig-van-beethoven_330.jpg} & & \includegraphics[width=0.33\fullwidth,height=1.5cm]{pablo-picasso_330.jpg} \tabularnewline
  \cmidrule[\signaturerulewidth]{1-1} \cmidrule[\signaturerulewidth]{3-3}
 %& & \tabularnewline
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries Signature} & & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries Signature} \tabularnewline
\end{tabularx}

}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the editing! Is it possible to move the word "signature" right underneath the line and at the same time make it centered? Like it is shown it on the second attached picture.

Comment: @code6reaker: Sorry, for the delay, I was off-line the whole day. Sure, the `Signature` can be centered by replacing the `r` specifier in the `\multicolumns` and the vertical spacing can be reduced by removing the empty table row. I've edited the code, but not updated the screen-shot